# Checking if multiple vectors are palindromatic?

Tags: java, vector, stack, queue

I created a program that reads a `String` from a file, and checks if it's a palindrome or not. Now I need to change it to check if vectors are palindromes or not. I have to create several vectors and check to see if they're palindromes. Say I've got the following vectors

```
(1,2,3), (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (2,2,2), (1,1,1), (1,2,3)
```

The program would use two iterators, and check if the first is equal to the last, if the second is equal to the second to last, and so on. This is my program for `String` inputs:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Project4
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Vector v1 = new Vector(3);
        Vector v2 = new Vector(3);
        Vector v3 = new Vector(3);
        Vector v4 = new Vector(3);
        ArrayList vectors = new ArrayList();
        v1.add(1);
        v1.add(2);
        v1.add(3);
        v2.add(1);
        v2.add(1);
        v2.add(1);
        v3.add(1);
        v3.add(1);
        v3.add(1);
        v4.add(1);
        v4.add(2);
        v4.add(3);
        vectors.add(v1);
        vectors.add(v2);
        vectors.add(v3);
        vectors.add(v4);
        if (isPalindrome(vectors))// If true, it's a palindrome
            System.out.println("That is a palindrome.");
        else // otherwise, it's not
            System.out.println("That is not a palindrome.");

    }
    public static boolean isPalindrome(ArrayList vectors)
    {
        // Make a new queue, stack, and character object
        Queue<Vector> q = new LinkedList<>();
        Stack<Vector> s = new Stack<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < vectors.size(); i++){
            q.add((Vector) vectors.get(i));
            s.add((Vector) vectors.get(i));
        }
        Vector temp = new Vector();
        int mismatches = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vectors.size(); i++)
        {
            temp = (Vector) vectors.get(i);
            if (vectors.get(i).equals(vectors.get(i)))
            {
                q.add(temp);
                s.push(temp);
            }
        }

        while (!q.isEmpty())
        {
            if (q.remove() != s.pop())
                mismatches++; // Increment "mismatches" if q != s
        }

        return (mismatches == 0); // will return true if the method did not change the variable "mismatches"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (pretty straightforward). Read comments in code to see how it works.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] b = { 1, 2, 1 };
    int[] c = { 1, 2, 2, 1 };
    int[] d = { 1, 2, 3, 1 };
    int[] e = { 1 };
    System.out.println(is_palindrome(a));
    System.out.println(is_palindrome(b));
    System.out.println(is_palindrome(c));
    System.out.println(is_palindrome(d));
    System.out.println(is_palindrome(e));

}

public static boolean is_palindrome(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) { // Check just half times the size of 'arr'
        // System.out.println(arr[i] + " - " + arr[arr.length - i - 1]); // Debug
        if (arr[i] != arr[arr.length - i - 1]) // Check 'first' with 'last', 'second' with 'last - 1' ...
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
true
false
true
```

Comment: Upvoted. This is the 'canonical' way to test whether something is a palindrome. Clear, well commented.

Comment: This works for the numbers inside of the arrays you made, but I have to check if a group of vectors are palindromatic. So, an array needs to be filled with vectors, each vector probably containing 3 separate numbers, and then it has to check if the first and last vectors are the same, the second and second to last, etc. So (1,2,3) and (1,2,3) would be equal, and if we just had those two in the array that I need to check for a palindrome, then it WOULD be palindromatic. On top of it all, I HAVE to use queues and stacks in the is_palindrome method.

Comment: Probably containing 3, or definitely? Makes a difference. Also, this sounds like homework or something if you **have** to use stacks and queues.

Comment: Would you believe if I told you the world would implode if I tried to write this program without queues? :I

Comment: This could easily be done without stack and queues. If this is your homework you should show more effort, you just posted your code with `String`, but you didn't show an attempt to do it with the vectors you mentioned.

Comment: I have been working on making vectors work, I posted the last bit of code that I could even get to run

Comment: @TonyWhite So can you tell us **why** you have to use stacks/queues? That's pulling out way heavier guns than you really need for this simple algorithm, making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: To aptly demonstrate the prowess of stacks and queues :I

Comment: @Keeler I've updated my question post with the newest version of my script. It doesn't work as intended though, it always evaluates to false. I think the problem is I didn't correctly open the arraylist and vector object to retrieve the number values inside, and so the palindrome checker is only looking at the addresses of the vector indexes... I don't know, I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to determine is whether or not the flattened list of integers is a palindrome. By flatten, I mean that if you flattened `[(3, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3)]`, it would become `[3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]` (which you can see is a palindrome).

You've got some problems with your code. As one example, why even check `vectors.get(i).equals(vectors.get(i))`? That will always evaluate to true.

This question smells of homework, so I'm not going to give you an implementation, but I will outline one.

In `isPalindrome(ArrayList vectors)`:

1. Push the front half of `vectors` onto the stack.
2. Enqueue the back half of `vectors` in the queue, *in reverse*.
3. Compare `x = q.remove()` and  `y = s.pop()` until you have no  more elements. If you think about it, the only way the flattened list can be a palindrome is if `x` and `y`, which are just lists of integers, are the reverse of each other.

And you can take it from there. There are a few ways that I can think of to implement this, in particular step 3.